# JavaFX 2.2 problems with native bundle(exe)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I have a Javafx 2.2 application that runs perfectly when I run it as a jar from netbeans 7.2 but when i create an exe and install the exe, it fails to run and throws an execption.

I don't get any logs to know where the error is coming from and this only occurs with only the exe.

Below is the ant target.

```
    <target name="-post-jfx-deploy">
    <fx:deploy width="${javafx.run.width}" height="${javafx.run.height}" 
               nativeBundles="exe"
               outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" outfile="${application.title}">
        <fx:application name="${application.title}" 
                        mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"/>
        <fx:permissions elevated="true"/>
        <fx:resources>
            <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}"
                        includes="*.jar"/>
        </fx:resources>
        <fx:info title="${application.title}" 
                 vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
        <fx:platform javafx="2.1+">
            <fx:jvmarg value="-Xmx400m"/>
            <fx:jvmarg value="-verbose:jni"/>
        </fx:platform> 
    </fx:deploy>          
</target>
```

[image]

Comment: Can u provide text or screenshot of an exception?

Comment: I have attached the error screenshot as requested

Comment: Unfortunately, this one is not very helpful. Can you enable Java Console (http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) and see if there is any messages there?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to setup log4j so i can do some logging of the internal state of the application and all of a sudden the error vanished.

Apparently it was because log4j had not been setup properly while the log4.jar was on the classpath or somehow but by adding log4j.xml to the path, the error has vanished. Thank you for the help.